# How to combine 2 strings into 1 array?

Tags: php, arrays

my problem is I want to combine [1] with [2]. 
The source is "20100930-storage-primary.csv" but I only want "storage-primary". Can you help me?

**This is the script I use to explode them:**

```
$Name = 20100930-storage-primary.csv;
 $array = explode( '.' , $Name);
 $array1 = explode( '-' , $array[0]);

var_dump ($array1);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "20100930" [1]=> string(7) "storage" [2]=> string(7) "primary" }
```

Comment: what is expected output you want?

Comment: the output I want is: "storage-primary"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `unset`,`implode` functions

```
$Name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
 $array = explode( '.' , $Name);
 $array1 = explode( '-' , $array[0]);
 unset($array1[0]);
 $str = implode('-',$array1);
 print_r($str);

var_dump ($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your string pattern won't change then this should work,

```
substr($Name, strpos($Name,'-',1) + 1, strpos($Name,'.',1) - strpos($Name,'-',1) - 1)
```

Try it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 unset($array1[0]);
 $str = implode('-',$array1);
 echo $str;
```

> OR

```
echo $array1[1]."-".$array1[2];
```

Output will be **storage-primary**